# How do you create a CheckedListBox WinForm control that is completely unresponsive to keyboard input?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkedlistbox

I tried creating a custom CheckedListBox and overriding the OnKeyUp, OnKeyPress, OnKeyDown, OnPreviewKeyDown methods but I couldn't accomplish what I wanted to accomplish.

Essentially what is happening now is that if the user presses a key while the CheckedListBox has focus, the selected item changes. For example, if the user presses the up or down key, the next/previous item in the CheckedListBox is selected. if the user presses 'A', then the first item that begins with the letter 'A' is selected.

I want the CheckedListBox to behave in such a way that it is completely unresponsive to key presses (but still responsive to mouse clicks).

Can someone please tell me how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is possible to achieve this by inheriting from CheckedListBox and overriding it's [ProcessCmdKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey.aspx) method to return true. That should ignore all commands.

I'll give it a try in a solution and report back :)

**Update:**

It works.
Code I used:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class CheckedListBoxIgnoreKeyboard : CheckedListBox
{
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

A rebuild is required for the control to show up in Toolbox.

Comment: @JohnSmith: I just tested it and when I press a button coresponding to a first letter of an element inside the control, nothing happens.

Comment: I apologize for the misinformation. I had code inside the KeyUp event handler procedure which was messing things up.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use the KeyDown event with this?

```
  e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
```

seem, on my side to work